# Dropdown Menu and switch to new Window in Selenium Webdriver not working in Firefox

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse, firefox, selenium

I am trying to automate few web pages i.e. Case creation, Accounts and Contacts creation through my developer login at www.salesforce.com. I am using Mozilla Firefox 34.0.5 alongwith Eclipse Luna and Java for automation using Selenium WebDriver. I am also using JExcel API for reading data from excel file in hard disk. System Specifications are Windows7 Ultimate 32 bit.

My automation code is working fine with Google Chrome but in Firefox certain fields on webpage such as dropdown menu Boxes, popup windows & switching control to new popup window are not working. I have not found any solution to this problem. I can't understand the reason for failure of selenium command : "selectByVisibleText(String)".

1. The dropdown menu list is displayed and the specified option is also highlighted but then click/select action is aborted and default value is selected.
2. With popup windows, selenium command : "driver.switchTo().window(windowhandle)" is not working. New pop window opens and window handle is generated but the error displayed is "Unable to locate window {window Handle String}".

I can't figure out why it can't locate the window by window handle and switch to it in firefox if it works fine in other browsers ??

Below is my Complete Code

```
public class PoiExcelCase {

    WebDriver driver;
    FileInputStream fis;
    HSSFWorkbook wb;
    HSSFSheet sh;

    @BeforeTest
    public void login() throws BiffException, IOException
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        //driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        fis = new FileInputStream(new File("D:/Salesforce.xls"));
        wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet1");
        driver.navigate().to("http://www.salesforce.com/in/?ir=1");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='button-login']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='username']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='password']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Login']")).click();
    }

    @Test
    public void caseSF() throws InterruptedException 
    {
          driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
          sh = wb.getSheet("Sheet4");
          WebElement we;
          String str;
          we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsidLabel']"));

          if(we.getText().equals("Sales")==false)
          {
            we.click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='tsid-menuItems']/a[text()='Sales']")).click();
          }

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='Case_Tab']/a")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.name("new")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas3_lkwgt']/img")).click();
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            String mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

            Set<String> winhandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
            System.out.println(winhandles.size());
            for(String st : winhandles)
            {
                System.out.println(st);
                driver.switchTo().window(st);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
            }
            /*
            Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles();
            Iterator<String> ite = s.iterator();
            while(ite.hasNext())
            {
                String popup = ite.next();
                if(!popup.equalsIgnoreCase(mainwindow))
                    driver.switchTo().window(popup);
            }
            */
            try
            {
                driver.switchTo().frame("resultsFrame");
                driver.findElement(By.linkText("Suresh Verma")).click();
                driver.switchTo().window(mainwindow);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                str = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas4']")).getAttribute("value");
                System.out.println(str);
                try
                {
                    Assert.assertEquals(str, sh.getRow(2).getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
                }
                catch(Throwable e)
                {
                    System.out.println("Incorrect Account Name");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println("I am in catch block");
                driver.close();
                driver.switchTo().window(mainwindow);
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas3']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(2).getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas4']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(2).getCell(2).getStringCellValue());
            }

            we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas5']"));
            we.click();
            Select se;
            se = new Select(we);
            se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(3).getStringCellValue());

            we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas6']"));
            se = new Select(we);
            we.click();
            se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(4).getStringCellValue());

            we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas7']"));
            se = new Select(we);
            we.click();
            se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(5).getStringCellValue());

            we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas8']"));
            se = new Select(we);
            we.click();
            se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(6).getStringCellValue());

            we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas11']"));
            se = new Select(we);
            we.click();
            se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(7).getStringCellValue());

            we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N9000000Ctc7c']"));
            se = new Select(we);
            we.click();
            se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(8).getStringCellValue());

            we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N9000000Ctc7b']"));
            se = new Select(we);
            we.click();
            se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(9).getStringCellValue());

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N9000000Ctc7a']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(2).getCell(10).getStringCellValue());

            we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='00N9000000Ctc7d']"));
            se = new Select(we);
            we.click();
            se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(11).getStringCellValue());

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas14']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(2).getCell(12).getStringCellValue());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas15']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(2).getCell(13).getStringCellValue());
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas16']")).sendKeys(sh.getRow(2).getCell(14).getStringCellValue());

            if(sh.getRow(2).getCell(15).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas21']")).click();
            if(sh.getRow(2).getCell(16).getStringCellValue().equalsIgnoreCase("Yes"))
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas22']")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bottomButtonRow']/input[1]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[text()='Details']")).click();

            Point pt = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='bodyTable']/tbody/tr/td/div/div[3]")).getLocation();
            ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,"+pt.getY()+");");
            Thread.sleep(10000);

            driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='topButtonRow']/input[4]")).click();

            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();

            //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@name='cancel']")).click();

    }

    @AfterTest
    public void logout() throws InterruptedException 
    {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//span[@id='userNavLabel']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//a[text()='Logout']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.close();
    }

}
```

Output displayed on execution in Firefox is as under:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  C:\Users\psit\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--1537148127\testng-customsuite.xml

2
{2cba4b8b-1677-425e-8d8c-a153c500d5a4}
Case Edit: New Case ~ salesforce.com - Developer Edition
{07c35b20-263d-4a1a-9e4e-c6a4be6e1162}
FAILED: caseSF
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to locate window "{07c35b20-263d-4a1a-9e4e-c6a4be6e1162}"
Command duration or timeout: 2.08 seconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'USER2', ip: '192.168.1.102', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=true, rotatable=false, handlesAlerts=true, databaseEnabled=true, version=34.0.5, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=false, acceptSslCerts=true, webStorageEnabled=true, locationContextEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 5e1ead01-1d29-4c4a-9821-729b1768547e
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:882)
    at apache_poi.PoiExcelCase.caseSF(PoiExcelCase.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:714)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to locate window "{07c35b20-263d-4a1a-9e4e-c6a4be6e1162}"
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'
System info: host: 'USER2', ip: '192.168.1.102', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at <anonymous class>.nsCommandProcessor.prototype.switchToWindow(file:///C:/Users/psit/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5017770494986140267webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11725:19)
    at <anonymous class>.nsCommandProcessor.prototype.switchToWindow/<(file:///C:/Users/psit/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous5017770494986140267webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:11729:9)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@1192d32: 142 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@ed3ef1: 16 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 15 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@d17bee: 63 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@3534aa: 15 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@16432db: 16 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find my answers inline:

**1 - The dropdown menu list is displayed and the specified option is also highlighted but then click/select action is aborted and default value is selected.**

You've clicked on the dropdown first and then tried to select the item, which you don't need to do. Just creating the `"Select class"` object and using **`selectByVisibleText("text to be selected")`** will do the trick as shown below (**just an excerpt taken from your code and modified as necessary**)

```
        we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas7']"));
        se = new Select(we);
        se.selectByVisibleText(sh.getRow(2).getCell(5).getStringCellValue());
```

**2 - With popup windows, selenium command : "driver.switchTo().window(windowhandle)" is not working. New pop window opens and window handle is generated but the error displayed is "Unable to locate window {window Handle String}".**

First get the main window handle, then click on the element that brings about the new window handle, and switch to the new window using the below code(**Again I have just modified the excerpt from your code**)

```
        String mainwindow = driver.getWindowHandle();        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='cas3_lkwgt']/img")).click();//Assuming clicking on this element brings out the new window

        Set<String> s = driver.getWindowHandles(); 
        Iterator<String> ite = s.iterator(); 
        while(ite.hasNext()) 
        { 
            String popup = ite.next(); 
            if(!popup.equalsIgnoreCase(mainwindow)){ 
                driver.switchTo().window(popup); 
                break;
              }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Subh....Clicking on select element was the reason behind the problem in Firefox. And in the second issue, I had tried the same while loop but a break was missing. Sometimes small mistakes are hard to detect and the whole program gets stuck.

Comment: @DeepakDave : True that.. That's why we keep practising to avoid 'em.. Cheers.. :)